# Calling function from Go in C#

Tags: c#, go, dll, cgo

I'm trying to make a .dll file from Golang to be used in a C# script. However, I can't make a simple example work.

Here is my Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {}

//export Test 
func Test(str *C.char) {
    fmt.Println("Hello from within Go")
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("A message from Go: %s", C.GoString(str)))
}
```

Here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            GoFunctions.Test("world");
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
        }
    }


    static class GoFunctions
    {
    [DllImport(@<path to test.dll>, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void Test(string str);
    }
}
```

I'm building the dll from:

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o test.dll <path to go file>
```

The output is

```
Hello
Hello from within Go
A message from Go: w

panic: runtime error: growslice: cap out of range
```

Comment: Without fully knowing Go, it looks like you're at least getting the first character of the string before it breaks. Could it be because you're typecasting as `*C.char` rather than a simple `string`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with `byte[]` instead of `string`, that is, with the following C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            GoFunctions.Test(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("world"));
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
        }
    }


    static class GoFunctions
    {
    [DllImport(@<path to test.dll>, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void Test(byte[] str);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why `string` does not work here though.